# What's the use of で at the end of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation, particle-で, nouns

> よかった　ご無事で！

so is it for emphasis? and if yes mostly men use it or women? and when doing Japanese people usually use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence is supposed to be ご無事でよかった！ but for what ever reason (perhaps the feeling of relief the speaker felt was particularly strong) よかった came out first, and ご無事で was added onto the end to make sure the listener knows what exactly what was よかった. This is perfectly natural, and we often do this in speech and writing imitating speech, but in formal writing this is frowned upon.

To clarify, this is NOT a sentence-final particle and has nothing to do with the gender or age of the speaker.